# Dollar sign in environment variable's value

Tags: environment-variables, pam-environment

Is it a bad practice to have a dollar sign in an environment variable's value?

ex:

```bsh
MY_VAR="$toto"
```

To be more precise, I would like to set it in the `/etc/environment` file to be accessible by a java program. I did a test and it's working but I just want to make sure I won't encounter any catastrophic side effect.
The value of the variable is a password and starts with a dollar sign so I have no choice.

Comment: That is fine as that is being used to assign the MY_VAR variable from whatever the variable of $toto is set to.  I have learned it is probably best to expand the variable by using {} around it.  MY_VAR=${toto}

Comment: Note that if this question is about `/etc/environment`, bash doesn't enter the picture. `/etc/environment` syntax is only coincidentally similar to bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the specific case of `/etc/environment`, no, a `$` in the variable value doesn't mean anything special. `/etc/environment` is a file read by a PAM module named [`pam_env`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/pam_env.8), and `pam_env` has specific syntax for interpreting `$`:

1. In `/etc/environment`, it is left uninterpreted.
2. In [`/etc/security/pam_env.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/pam_env.conf.5) and `~/.pam_environment` (a user-specific file), `pam_env` treats `$` specially when it sees lines with the following syntax:

   ```
   FOO DEFAULT=SOMETHING${BAR}SOMETHINGELSE$BAR
   FOO OVERRIDE=SOMETHING${BAR}SOMETHINGELSE$BAR
   ```

   In this case, `${BAR}` is replaced with the value of the variable `BAR`, but not `$BAR`.

In both cases, for a line like:

```
FOO=BAR$BAR${BAR}
```

The contents of the variable `FOO` will be the literal string `BAR$BAR${BAR}`.

The `pam_env.conf` manpage has examples:

```
Silly examples of escaped variables, just to show how they work.

         DOLLAR         DEFAULT=\$
         DOLLARDOLLAR   DEFAULT=        OVERRIDE=\$${DOLLAR}
         DOLLARPLUS     DEFAULT=\${REMOTEHOST}${REMOTEHOST}
         ATSIGN         DEFAULT=""      OVERRIDE=\@
```

Comment: Seeing some strange behavior with AWS Elastic Beanstalk, environment variables, and Python/Django: I've set the DB_USERNAME variable to "username$$$$$" in AWS, and on the Django side, I'm getting this error: "FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "username1062210622$""

Comment: @MikeT where did you set it?

Comment: in the configuration page of the environment within the elastic beanstalk gui. ended up removing the symbol

Answer (score 17):

Your example does not illustrate your question.

```
$ toto="somevalue"
$ MY_VAR="$toto"
$ echo $MY_VAR
somevalue
$
```

To do what you asked, you'd need:

```
MY_VAR='$toto'
```

or

```
MY_VAR="\$toto"
```

Can't tell for sure if it's bad practice. Personally I don't see any obvious problem.

Answer (score 8):

Many pointed out that `MY_VAR="$toto"` will assign to `MY_VAR` the current value of `$toto` or an empty string in case `$toto` is unset (or in case `$toto` itself contains an empty string obviously), but I'm surprised no one pointed out yet that `MY_VAR="$toto"` will *not* set an environment variable but rather a shell variable (unless a variable named `MY_VAR` is already present in the environment, perhaps because this is only tangential to the actual question).

However more to the point no, it's not a bad practice, or it's just as bad practice as having any other shell special character inside a variable, which is often not avoidable.

In 99% of the cases the shell will expand the variable in the current shell *only once* (or will not expand it at all for example when enclosed in single-quotes):

```bsh
$ MY_VAR='$toto'
$ echo $MY_VAR
$toto
$ echo '$MY_VAR'
$MY_VAR
$ echo "$MY_VAR"
$toto
$ echo $(echo $MY_VAR)
$toto
```

The 1% of the cases being, for example, when the variable is referenced in an `eval` expression, which adds a level of indirection:

```bsh
$ MY_VAR='$toto'
$ eval echo $MY_VAR

$
```

But that's obviously the expected result, and again, then having any other shell special character inside a variable should be considered a bad practice in the same way:

```bsh
$ MY_VAR='&&'
$ eval echo $MY_VAR
bash: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

(the truth being that *using `eval`* is often a bad practice, for this very reason).

So no, having a dollar sign in a shell / environment variable is not a bad practice, at least not more than having any other shell special character.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your exact question:

Yes, it is bad practice to have a dollar sign in the value of an environment variable.  However, that's not what the code snippet you have displayed actually does.

```
MY_VAR="$toto"
```

`$` is a special character to your shell (whether `bash` or `dash`), and unless protected against variable expansion, you won't actually be putting a literal dollar sign in the value of `MY_VAR`.

To do that you would need to escape the `$`, either with a backslash just before it, or single quotes around it.

Comment: So if it's a bad practice, which I think it might be the case, then what if you have to have an environment variable for which the value starts with a $ sign (like a password for example)?

Comment: @jon, see above.  You need to escape the `$`, either with a backlash or single quotes.  `MY_VAR=\$toto` or `MY_VAR='$toto'` (or even `MY_VAR='$t'o"t"\o`; these all do the same exact thing.)  And it's arguable whether or not it's really bad practice; it depends also on what the environment variable is to be used for.  Unless there is a good reason for it I would avoid having a literal dollar sign in environment variables.